# generator object <genexpr> at 0x09778430

Tags: python, list

Сгенерировал список из предложений,но за место самих предложений выдает это:generator object  at 0x09778430.Что делать?

Comment: Это не список, а генератор. Оберните его в `list()`.

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю, как вы «сгенерировали» ваш «список» — может быть, что вы хотели использовать *генератор списка*, но вместо *квадратных* скобок вы применили *круглые.*

**Помените их на квадратные.**

Пример:

```
(i * i for i in some_list)         # генератор — вы это не хотите
^                        ^

[i * i for i in some_list]         # список
^                        ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно обернуть генератор в `list`, а можно сгенерировать список из элементов генератора, если элементы ещё предстоит как-то модифицировать:

```
def modify(x):
    ...
    return modified_x

lst = [modify(x) for x in generator]
```

Answer (score 2):

Примените цикл `for` для печати элементов вашего «списка» (который нет списком, а генератором).

```
for element in your_generator:
    print(element)
```

Цикл `for` принудит генератор постепенно генерировать все элементы.